# golang struct array conversion

Tags: arrays, struct, go

I have structs like below:

```
type Foo struct{
  A string
  B string
}

type Bar struct{
  C string
  D Baz
}

type Baz struct{
  E string
  F string
}
```

Lets say I have `[]Bar`, how to convert this to `[]Foo` ?

`A` should be `C`

`B` should be `E`

Comment: Those structs are semantically different. Please describe why you want to do that conversion, maybe you can use an interface.

Comment: I'm using third party package for something, this package returns me a huge struct, I want to convert this struct to my local struct for insert to db.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's any "magic" way of doing the conversion. However, it is a very small piece of coding to create it. Something like this ought to do the trick.

```
func BarsToFoos(bs []Bar) []Foo {
  var acc []Foo

  for _, b := range bs {
    newFoo := Foo{A: b.C, B: b.D.E}  // pulled out for clarity
    acc = append(acc, newFoo)
  }

  return acc
}
```

Comment: @MelihMucuk yes, it should be enough. Over optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: I doubt there's a faster way to actually convert them. Depending on exactly what you're trying to do, it MAY be better to use an interface and skipping the explicit conversion.

Comment: I think it's better to define length and capacity of `acc` slice, to reduce memory allocations. Because we know that: `len(bs)`

Comment: That's sufficiently "micro" in optimization terms that I thought it would make the example less readable. But, sure, that's going to give you a slight run-time performace. I'd still bench-mark both versions with, say, 10, 100 and 1000 elements and see if it's actually worth it...

Comment: I'm not really sure that `acc := make([]Foo, 0, len(bs))` is less readable

Comment: Premature one was Donald Trump's quote, this one is mine :P

Comment: @RoninDev Sure it is, I suddenly need to double-check that you're taking the length of the right element. Not *much* less readable, I admit. Definitely something I would consider, if I could show that there was a clear advantage to the lessened readability. It's in the same realm of "I can grab my mug by just moving my hand" or "I have to stretch and lean, just a smidgen". Eventually, it builds up.

Comment: HAHHAHAHAA I should get a coffee.. can't stop laughing

Comment: @MelihMucuk: To be performant in Go, which manages memory, minimize memory allocations and use. To provide constant cost, `append` over allocates. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For example, concisely mininimizing memory allocations and use,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    A string
    B string
}

type Bar struct {
    C string
    D Baz
}

type Baz struct {
    E string
    F string
}

func FooFromBar(bs []Bar) []Foo {
    fs := make([]Foo, 0, len(bs))
    for _, b := range bs {
        fs = append(fs, Foo{
            A: b.C,
            B: b.D.E,
        })
    }
    return fs
}

func main() {
    b := []Bar{{C: "C", D: Baz{E: "E", F: "F"}}}
    fmt.Println(b)
    f := FooFromBar(b)
    fmt.Println(f)
}
```

Output:

```
[{C {E F}}]
[{C E}]
```